# Why is plt taking so long?

Tags: matplotlib

I am tryng to visualize histograms of data. For this, I'm using:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import QuantileTransformer
import numpy as np

ey = np.random.pareto(15, size=30000)
qt = QuantileTransformer(output_distribution='normal')
no = qt.fit_transform(ey.reshape(-1, 1))

# Plot histograms to see before vs after.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline 
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
plt.hist(ey, bins='auto')
plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
plt.hist(no, bins='auto')
plt.show()
```

This runs perfectly well within a few seconds.

Now if I take some real data from my dataframe as such:

```
ey = train.target_reg.values # instead of ey = np.random.pareto(15, size=30000)
plt.hist(ey, bins='auto')
```

The rendering time suddenly goes sky high and I never get my histogram. Have been waiting on it for an hour now.

What on Earth can cause this? Both `ey`s have around 30 thousand pieces of data, both are `float64` and both have a similar distribution.

What can cause the difference?

Comment: Are you sure your data aren't in string format?  Did you try to set some fixed value for bins? (The "auto" option can get bad when points are included far away from the rest.  See a.o. https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/11879 ).

Comment: Yeah, `,dtype` shows `float64`. Limiting the bins to a few hundred solved it!